# list items nested within another list items . how to bring them one below another

Tags: html, css

Hi what I want is to make the nested `<li>` exactly below the above `<li>`.

[codepen.](http://codepen.io/rohit-dev/pen/jqKPmR?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your css file:

```
#A ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

also you need to change the `text-align:center;` to `text-align:left;` in `#B li`

Answer (score 0):

Set width for ul and make li as display block.

```
ul {
   width: 100px;           
}

ul li {
   display: block;
}
```